# Mysql "AS" returns empty result when using "UNION" mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to get **info_5** and **info_6**. My query is working fine
but **info_5** and **info_6** is always returns empty result. Could
you tell me what is wrong in my query?
Without info_5 and info_6 mysql query works fine too
I could not find any fix on
google and could not resolve problem.

1 Is there any alternative to select from multiple tables and different columns?

2 is my query secure?

```
(SELECT 'realestate' AS table_name, post_id,city,username,poster_folder_id,
    street AS info_1,
    post_condition AS info_2,
    post_type AS info_3,
    area AS info_4,
    blocked AS info_5,
    price AS info_6
    FROM realestate 
    USE INDEX(idx_post_id,idx_price,idx_username,idx_city,idx_poster_folder_id)
    ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 6)
UNION

(SELECT 'cars' AS table_name, post_id,city,username,poster_folder_id,
    model AS info_1, 
    modelsnumber AS info_2,
    post_type AS info_3,
    fueltype AS info_4,
    post_year AS  info_5,
    price AS info_6
    FROM cars 
    USE INDEX(idx_post_id,idx_price,idx_city,idx_username,idx_poster_folder_id)
    ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 6)
UNION

(SELECT 'spectechnic' AS table_name, post_id,city,username,poster_folder_id,
    model AS info_1, 
    modelsnumber AS info_2,
    post_type AS info_3,
    fueltype AS info_4,
    post_year AS info_5,
    price AS info_6
    FROM spectechnic 
    USE INDEX(idx_post_id,idx_price,idx_city,idx_username,idx_poster_folder_id)
    ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 6)
UNION

(SELECT 'motorcycles' AS table_name,post_id,city,username,poster_folder_id,
    model AS info_1, 
    modelsnumber AS info_2,
    post_type AS info_3,
    fueltype AS info_4,
    post_year AS info_5,
    price AS info_6
    FROM motorcycles 
    USE INDEX(idx_post_id,idx_price,idx_city,idx_username,idx_poster_folder_id)
    ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 6)
UNION

(SELECT 'parts' AS table_name, post_id,city,username,poster_folder_id,
    model AS info_1, 
    modelsnumber AS info_2,
    post_type AS info_3,
    warranty AS info_4,
    sellorbuy AS info_5,
    price AS info_6
    FROM parts 
    USE INDEX(idx_post_id,idx_price,idx_city,idx_username,idx_poster_folder_id)
    ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 6)
UNION

(SELECT 'beauty' AS table_name, post_id,city,username,poster_folder_id,
    modelsnumber AS info_1, 
    modelsnumber AS info_2,
    post_type AS info_3,
    post_views AS info_4,
    blocked AS info_5,
    price AS info_6
    FROM beauty 
    USE INDEX(idx_post_id,idx_price,idx_city,idx_username,idx_poster_folder_id)
    ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 6)
```

Comment: You have a `LIMIT 6` to each query which means it will show only 6 records. Can you check your date by removing this clause?  Also, i do not think there is any alternate to your UNION query - but you can insert them separately using each union query instead of one single query. Secure or not- in what sense ? For sure, its going to be poorly performing query if tables are huge.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What's the point of `USE INDEX`? You have no `WHERE` conditions that need to use an index, only `ORDER BY`, and it should naturally use the index on that column.

Comment: What are the datatypes of the columns that you're putting into `info_5` and `info_6`. Since you're merging them into a union, you may need to use `CAST()` to convert them all to a common datatype.

Comment: @KoushikRoy What does the `LIMIT` have to do with this problem? They should get up to 6 rows from each table, for a total of 36 rows.

Comment: Need info on the table structure, to know if the field `blocked` is of the same type as `post_year`.

Comment: @Tedo Dhdhdjdodk, if you have first 6 record with null data then you will get null result. You can pick up one record and run this sql to test it out.

Comment: From the 6 occurrences of `USE INDEX`, only one uses a different index, is that correct?

Comment: @TedoDhdhdjdodk  . . . The most obvious conclusion is that the most recent six rows in all the table have `NULL` values in these columns.

Comment: @Barmar type is varchar and longtext

Comment: I would remove the use index parts. Telling the database to use another index than what it chose for itself is really an expert level thing. The database will almost always choose the correct index as long as you created them correctly.

Comment: `post_year` and `price` are varchar and longtext, not numeric types? That seems very strange. Can you create a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Without access to your tables it is rather hard to know why you are getting NULLs in info_5 and info_6. It is possible that there simply is no data in the source columns, or no data in those columns for the most chosen posts.

I would make the following suggestions:

1. use UNION ALL, because each subquery has its unique "tablename" you won't get removal of duplicates by using UNION (see example below)
2. remove the USE INDEX instructions
3. do try using `CAST` in the info_5 and info_6 columns, below I have used varchar(40) just as an example it could be more or less than 40, that's up to you
4. optional: use WHERE clauses to locate data in the source columns for info_5 and info_6

```
(SELECT 'realestate' AS table_name, post_id,city,username,poster_folder_id,
    street AS info_1,
    post_condition AS info_2,
    post_type AS info_3,
    area AS info_4,
    cast(blocked as varchar(40)) AS info_5,
    cast(price as varchar(40)) AS info_6
    FROM realestate 
    WHERE blocked IS NOT NULL price IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 6)
    
UNION ALL

(SELECT 'cars' AS table_name, post_id,city,username,poster_folder_id,
    model AS info_1, 
    modelsnumber AS info_2,
    post_type AS info_3,
    fueltype AS info_4,
    cast(post_year as varchar(40)) AS  info_5,
    cast(price AS as varchar(40)) info_6
    FROM cars 
    WHERE post_year IS NOT NULL OR price IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 6)
    
UNION ALL
    ... continue with the other subqueries
```

tip: Perhaps try each subquery with these where clauses separately before running the overall.

Regarding `UNION` (removes duplicated rows) and `UNION ALL` the latter variant does less work than the former, so when you don't really need to remove duplicates opt for `UNION ALL`

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT
);
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (2);

SELECT 'realestate' AS table_name, id FROM test
UNION
SELECT 'cars' AS table_name, id FROM test
order by table_name, id

+------------+----+
| table_name | id |
+------------+----+
| cars       |  1 |
| cars       |  2 |
| realestate |  1 |
| realestate |  2 |
+------------+----+

SELECT 'realestate' AS table_name, id FROM test
UNION ALL
SELECT 'cars' AS table_name, id FROM test
order by table_name, id

+------------+----+
| table_name | id |
+------------+----+
| cars       |  1 |
| cars       |  2 |
| realestate |  1 |
| realestate |  2 |
+------------+----+
```

As you can see above UNION didn't do anything more useful that UNION ALL, yet UNION ALL is "cheaper" to run as it does less work. In such cases choose UNION ALL.

You also ask if there are alternatives to using union/union all when you have different tables and columns. I would say no there isn't an alternative if just using SQL. However when using union/union all you do need to pay attention to the data types of the source columns and they must be compatible for the entire column.

Finally you ask if it is secure. Well as there are no apparent parameters so it is safe from SQL injection but that's about all I can say about that.